# Have there been any (interesting) computer-aided proofs that weren't proof-by-exhaustion?

Tags: proof-writing, math-history, computer-assisted-proofs

It seems to me like many of the most famous "computer proofs" were done by basically brute-forcing through all of the cases, such as the four color map theorem. Are there any good examples of computer proofs that did not use this strategy? What strategy did they use?

EDIT: I suppose there have been many proofs by example/counterexample too. I would probably not qualify these as "interesting" unless there's another reason to do so.

Comment: As far as I know, the computer was used to check some problematic cases for the four-color theorem, not all possible cases!

Comment: When you say "computer proofs", do you necessarily mean for problems where the first proof was computer related?

Comment: @MarkS. Not necessarily, that might be preferable, but any examples are welcome!

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/89374/j-e-pin) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1696029) might be of interest to you.